# Using VBA to open and SAVEAS selected Website files

Tags: vba

As a learning exercise and to do something productive, I decided to write a VBA macro for one of my "very old" FrontPage websites.  Actually I'm in the process of trying to escape from FrontPage(FP)...

This seemingly simple project, I am familiar with VBA for Excel and Access, was to open a series of current web pages in FP and save them to a different folder so I could begin to remove all of the FP stuff without affecting the working parts of the website.

I Google-ed "FrontPage" and "VBA" extensively but there seems to be a dearth of useful information out there.  Any references I did find pointed to pages/sites that are no longer active.  So I muddled along with what information I did find and this is the result:

```
Sub OpenAndSaveAsPages()
Dim objPageWindow As PageWindowEx
Dim objFileOpen As FileDialog
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFile As Variant
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim strURL As String
'File Open dialog object.
Set objFileOpen = FrontPage.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
'startup folder default is the root folder of the active Web site
strFolder = ActiveWeb.RootFolder
' clean up unwanted stuff in the URL
strFolder = Replace(strFolder, "file:///", "")
strFolder = Replace(strFolder, "/", "\")
objFileOpen.InitialFileName = strFolder
If objFileOpen.Show < 0 Then
    For Each strFile In objFileOpen.SelectedItems
' Open web file in FP
        ActiveWebWindow.PageWindows.Add strFile
' at this point all I wanted to do was a SAVEAS to save the file to a different folder
' so I wanted to do something like below but could not figure it out
'           objPageWindow.SaveAs objPageWindow.Document.Url
    Next
End If
' Now all the selected file are open in FrontPage and I will iterate through them
For Each objPageWindow In ActiveWebWindow.PageWindows
' the URL for the currently select page
    strURL = objPageWindow.Document.Url
' probably some extra work here to change the URL to a different folder and filename
    strURL = Replace(strURL, Mid(strURL, InStrRev(strURL, ".", Len(strURL)), Len(strURL) + 1 - InStrRev(strURL, ".", Len(strURL))), Mid(strURL, InStrRev(strURL, ".", Len(strURL)), Len(strURL) + 1 - InStrRev(strURL, ".", Len(strURL))), 1)
    strURL = Replace(strURL, Left(strURL, InStrRev(strURL, "/", Len(strURL))), Left(strURL, InStrRev(strURL, "/", Len(strURL))) & "temp/", 1)
    objPageWindow.SaveAs strURL
    objPageWindow.Close
Next
End Sub
```

OK, it works but for sure it is probably not the most efficient and for sure not elegant.

So, my questions are:

1. are there and good references for FP VBA that you can recommend (I'm not a professional programmer, just someone that like to ...).  I work well in using examples to achieve and  learn.
2. Can someone sharpen up my code, with explanations, of course.

Note, I'm not trying to write any code to actually modify the code in these pages.  I may get to that, but for now it appears that a "SAVEAS" results in code which is already fairly clean of the FP stuff.

Many thanks....RDK

ps....I previously posted this on another StackExchange site (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74813304/vba-for-frontpage ) where  it was recommended that I post it here...

Comment: Microsoft discontinued support for FrontPage, the last release was in 2003, support for it would have ended after 10 years at the most. Websites using front page extensions became targets for hackers. Almost all hosting companies removed FrontPage web sites a long time ago to protect the servers. Visual Basic (VB) rather than VBA is a web programming language currently. I personally would use C# over VB.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) works in FrontPage, ... for science! There aren't any FP-specific inspections, but if it works it could be helpful with organizing and refactoring such a project.

Comment: OK, Thanks for the comments, bur since it is working, albeit probably not the most elegant, I leave i t alone.  Thanks again...